# How do providers auto scale VMs when powered by VMWare

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I'm trying to figure out what component of vSphere or other VMWare product is used to manage automatic scaling of resources for individual VMs in the way that these two providers describe:

http://vps.net/cloud-servers/flexible-cloud

http://www.singlehop.com/blog/launching-our-new-vmware-powered-public-cloud-autoscaling-san-based-storage-and-a-whole-lot-more/

I've seen you can run triggered workflows with orchestrator, and you can trigger new vApp deployments with vFabric, but they are both outside of an individual VM as far as I can tell.